# Browser not launching at all using selenium java

Tags: selenium

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--start-maximized", "allow-running-   insecure-content", "ignore-certificate-errors"));         capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 
WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://www.google.com"), capabilities);
```

### webDriver.findElement.....

I have the above piece of code to start a browser and go to a URL. I did a 
1. brew install chromedriver
2. i made sure /usr/local/bin is in the path variable.
3. When i run the above peice of code it fails in find Element giving a null pointer exception. 
I am running mac os.. how can i fix the problem. i did lot of work arounds, the same code without capabilities and just giving the chromedriver path was working before.. not sure why i am not able to get it to run..

Comment: Why are you using RemoteWebDriver? Try with ChromeDriver(.........) and driver.get("google....")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest chrome driver fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to your problem:

Make sure you want to use RemoteWebDriver. If you do you will want to set up a Selenium Grid with a chrome node. I won't describe how to set it up here, but it is fairly easy to set up a local grid+nodes using docker: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium
If you do use this, you will need to change the driver to (assuming the grid is on the localhost):

```
String hubURL = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
WebDriver webDriver = RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), capabilities);
```

Or Use the ChromeDriver class instead of RemoteWebDriver:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Finally, to go to a webpage, you'll need to use the `get` method on the driver:

```
webDriver.get(url);
```

Comment: I have the below code now. Browser is not getting launched..      
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--start-maximized", "allow-running-   insecure-content",
                                          "ignore-certificate-errors"));
      capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
      webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
      webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      webDriver.navigate().to(url);

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when i say ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver()

Comment: what exactly is null?